# Cannot create new output file. Standard out is used. Adding class labels to weka

Tags: java, jar, weka, arff

I have extracted features using jaudio from GTZAN dataset.
Trying to add genre class label to  arff file using java code. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;


public class AddAttribute
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("\nUsage: java AddAttribute <file.arff> <genre>\n");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String filename = args[0];
    String genre = args[1];

    // load dataset
    Instances data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
    Instances newData = new Instances(data);
    // add new attribute        
    FastVector values = new FastVector();
    values.addElement("jazz");
    values.addElement("pop");
    values.addElement("metal");
    values.addElement("classical");
    Attribute genreAttr = new Attribute("Genre", values);
    newData.insertAttributeAt(genreAttr, newData.numAttributes());

    // add to each instance
    for (int i = 0; i < newData.numInstances(); i++) {
        newData.instance(i).setValue(newData.numAttributes() - 1, genre);
    }

    // save back to the original arff file
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(newData);
    saver.setFile(new File(filename));
    saver.writeBatch();
}
}
```

it gives the following error. 
**Cannot create new output file. Standard out is used.**

Comment: You can try to use different files for input and output. Once finished, remove the old file and rename the new file to the old filename.

Comment: @Henry could you please tell me how?